# Altova Mapforce - How to use results from Tokenize at the same time in a database call?

Tags: variables, tokenize, altova, map-force

At the moment I have this string format: "2134-123". Basically I need to split that string into both values, but I also need to use those at the same time to get information from a database table.

I have used tokenize with - as a delimiter, but that gives me a sequence. I've tried to use item-at two times with position 1 and 2, but the second value is always NULL. I know the sequence is correct, because when I use output to test, it says for example: "One or several additional values were skipped. The value "90105" was mapped. First skipped value(s): "4010"."

[image]

I need to map those two values to a database to get some output, how should I do this? Thanks.